# Write a binary counter in quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, source-layout

Write two code fragments, which we will call s_zero and s_one.

Program (l, n) consists of l copies of s_zero and s_one corresponding with the digits of n in binary, padded with s_zero on the left.

For example, if s_zero = `foo` and s_one = `bar` then
Program (4, 0) = `foofoofoofoo`
Program (4, 1) = `foofoofoobar`
Program (4, 2) = `foofoobarfoo`
etc.

Program (l, n) must print the source of Program (l, (n + 1) mod (2^l)) to standard out. In the example above, `foobarfoofoo` must print `foobarfoobar` when executed.

Your score is the sum of the lengths of fragments s_zero and s_one

Comment: Near duplicate to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35974/code-that-runs-the-game-of-life-on-itself - computation done by quining program with 2 different code blocks.

Comment: Can the program read its own source code?

Comment: @feersum I disagree. This one is a lot easier, in particular, you don't need to be able to determine line breaks. Furthermore, I think the task *does* make a difference, otherwise every generalised quine challenge would be a dupe of the basic quine challenge.

Comment: The advantage of the simpler task is that it encourages competition to create the shockingly short answers seen so far- I hope that justifies this challenge as different!

Comment: Probably worth noting that s_zero and s_one have to be different. Otherwise I have many solutions with 2*n scores.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 29 + 29 = 58 bytes

The 0 code:

```
0{"_~"]]z(3\+2b(2b2>a\+z~[}_~
```

The 1 code:

```
1{"_~"]]z(3\+2b(2b2>a\+z~[}_~
```

#### Explanation

```
0                       " Push the current bit. ";
{"_~"                   " The basic quine structure. ";
    ]                   " Make an array of the current bit, the function and _~.
                          That is the code fragment itself. ";
    ]                   " Make an array of all code fragments in the stack. ";
    z(                  " Extract the array of the bits. ";
    3\+2b(2b2>          " Convert from base 2, decrease by one and convert back,
                          keeping the length. ";
    a\+z                " Put the bits back to the original position. ";
    ~                   " Dump the array of code fragments back into the stack. ";
    [                   " Mark the beginning position of the array of the next code fragment. ";
}_~
```

Comment: every single time ...

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 47 + 47 = 94 bytes

The 0 code:

```
{`"_~"+]:+T2*0+:T)\AsSerS/_,(@2Y$#+2bU@->]zs}_~
```

The 1 code:

```
{`"_~"+]:+T2*1+:T)\AsSerS/_,(@2Y$#+2bU@->]zs}_~
```

Excuse the expletive.

I'm sure I can still shave off a few bytes there. I'll add an explanation once I decide that I can't be bothered to golf it any further.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>264 250</s> 120 + 120 = 240 bytes

### Code 0: (120 bytes)

```python
for i in(c:=[]),0:
 c+=0,;exec(s:="i or print(end=f'for i in(c:=[]),0:\\n c+={c[0]^all(c:=c[1:-1])},;exec(s:=%r)#'%s)")#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPI9nKNjpWU8fAikshWdvWQMc6tSI1WaPYylYpUwGopqAoM69EIzUvxTZNHVNPTEweSFd1crRBbFxiTg5IJjna0ErXMFazFmGUapGmsrpqsaaSpvL//wA)

### Code 1: (120 bytes)

```python
for i in(c:=[]),0:
 c+=1,;exec(s:="i or print(end=f'for i in(c:=[]),0:\\n c+={c[0]^all(c:=c[1:-1])},;exec(s:=%r)#'%s)")#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPI9nKNjpWU8fAikshWdvWUMc6tSI1WaPYylYpUwGopqAoM69EIzUvxTZNHVNPTEweSFd1crRBbFxiTg5IJjna0ErXMFazFmGUapGmsrpqsaaSpvL//wA)

### Test Suite

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZDRasIwFIbv8xSHiNjYOBqFbXTkLXZXO6gx1YyahDSCQ3z2LmltxzbY5S4Sfjj/f853jv3wR6M3z9Z1nciAg8MY18aBAqUTkfOiJDTLEYiUZ/RFXqRI2pxjBcFjndI@kXrP68XvzHarY@oqiqx8q5omVkTB8hUrye2r1dyR2WLeEkxmYTRCgv1Nwf6FAtXOnGB3Vo1XugV1ssb5YRRULViEzNnz4NzL@k6wvNAIgbcak4B6aMyuaiDYUPwg5YABP7ybQHchabAisGMoPIL6XsLsZdJIffBHqmMfJ/3ZacD3aCEyKlhZxImKlDBuDLtQXC@XQzTVpFgNMi/vnV9l68fOoH8i2qTG1pmDq05wHVw3Cld9yzFB0J/pOxqJmf6L23H@jRx0ygjtT9FvHy@FeoANzcio2KTWk9pM6nFST6TrPgE)

### How it works:

- `c` store the binary number of the program on the form of a list

The for loop execute twice :

- the first time, it assigns `c` to the correct value
- the second time, it prints the code replacing a char by 1 or 0 depending on `c`. The `n`th time `c[0]^all(c:=c[1:-1])` is called, it returns the `n`th leftmost bit of `c+1`

the next for loop are ignored thanks to the comment `#`

The printing is a derivate of this quine : `exec(s:="print('exec(s:=%r)'%s)")`

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 45 + 45 = 90 bytes

The **0** code:

```
{`]W=L0+:L,Ua*L2b)2b+L,W*>\f{X$!s/\s*"_~"}}_~
```

The **1** code:

```
{`]W=L1+:L,Ua*L2b)2b+L,W*>\f{X$!s/\s*"_~"}}_~
```

Explanation soon.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript, 37 + 37 = 74 bytes

```
0{`".~"+:q;]-2%1\{1$^.@&q@}%\;-1%~}.~
```

```
1{`".~"+:q;]-2%1\{1$^.@&q@}%\;-1%~}.~
```

Not quite as short as [user23013's CJam solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/44962), but I figured I'd post this anyway, if only to (marginally) increase the diversity of the languages used.

My solution not directly based on any of the existing solutions (and, indeed, I haven't examined them in detail, as I still don't read CJam very well), but they all feature variants of the same basic quine structure (`{".~"}.~` in GolfScript, `{"_~"}_~` in CJam).  That's not really very surprising, since it seems to be one of the most efficient ways to write a quine with an arbitrary payload in these languages.

There are several parts of this code I don't really like, and I suspect it may be possible to golf this further, but I've spent too much time on this as it is.